# how to get last date and the closest

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

```
table_ent                             |   table_out
cod_prod   date_ent     vl_prod       |   cod_prod   date_out       vl_prod  
362        14/09/2015   100,00        |   362        01/10/2016     700,00
362        15/09/2015   150,00        |   362        07/10/2016     800,00
362        16/09/2015   10,00         |   362        29/10/2016     100,00
362        05/10/2016   20,00         |   362        01/10/2016     800,00       
362        06/10/2016   300,00        |
362        07/10/2016   460,00        |
362        08/10/2016   510,00        |
362        23/10/2016   620,00        |
362        24/10/2016   750,00        |
362        25/10/2016   810,00        |
362        30/10/2019   920,00        |
```

I need to get the closest date using SQL inner join. I already tried `max (date)` but it did not work out; I got this:

```
cod_ent  date_out   vl_ent   cod_ent  vl_ent  date_ent
------   --------   ------   ---      ---     -------
362      01/10/16   700      362      100     14/09/15
362      01/10/16   800      362      10      16/09/15
362      01/10/16   700      362      150     15/09/15
362      01/10/16   700      362      10      16/09/15
362      01/10/16   800      362      150     15/09/15
362      01/10/16   800      362      100     14/09/15
362      07/10/16   100      362      20      05/10/16
362      07/10/16   100      362      300     06/10/16
362      07/10/16   100      362      100     14/09/15
362      07/10/16   100      362      10      16/09/15
362      07/10/16   100      362      150     15/09/15
362      29/10/16   920      362      510     08/10/16
362      29/10/16   920      362      750     24/10/16
362      29/10/16   920      362      460     07/10/16
362      29/10/16   920      362      10      16/09/15
```

Desired Result :

```
cod_ent  date_out   vl_ent   cod_ent  vl_ent  date_ent
------   --------   ------   ---      ---     -------
362      01/10/16   700      362      10      16/09/15
362      01/10/16   800      362      10      16/09/15
362      07/10/16   100      362      300     06/10/16
362      29/10/16   920      362      750     25/10/16
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the query you tried, and explain your logic a bit more perhaps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it helped me a lot.

Comment: I still have a problem with duplicate values when I add a new column
example:

Comment: select a.cod_prod, a.date_out, a.vl_prod, sum(b.cod_prod) as cod_prod, sum(b.vl_prod) vl_prod, max(b.date_ent) as date_ent
from table_out a
join table_ent b on b.cod_prod = a.cod_prod and b.date_ent < a.date_out
group by a.cod_prod, a.date_out, b.cod_prod, a.vl_prod, b.vl_prod
order by a.cod_prod, a.date_out;

Comment: You haven't shown a `vl_prod` column in your question, or how they're related. You might just need to add `and b.vl_prod = a.vl_prod` in the join condition, but that's just a guess. Or more likely remove `b.vl_prod` from the group-by clause.  If it isn't that simple then ask a new question showing sample data including that extra column, your current query and results for that data, and the logic and expected results.

Comment: I apologize, I edited the question and added the column, it has no relation to the values, I need to get the value of the last entry

Comment: No, don't change this question, it invalidates the existing answers. That's why I suggested you ask a *new* question. (Also see [how to format your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).) The main issue does seem to be that you've included `b.vl_prod` in the `group by`, which doesn't make sense as you're summing that column. Remove that and you'll be back to the original number of rows in the output.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Ignoring for the moment that you've again changed the question in a way that - at least partially - invalidates the existing answers, you still haven't explained your logic for your desired result; and it's even less clear now. Why do the two rows for 01/10/2016 have different values for the last two columns? Why does the third row have 100 instead of 800, and why 20? Why does the fourth row have 920 (?) instead of 100, and why 750? I can't figure out how you'd get to that result...

Comment: I made a mistake in the result values because I did manual, but the idea is to bring the biggest date and the closest date

Comment: correct the expected result

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve the output you showed is to join the two tables with a date comparison condition - this seems to be what you're after:

```
table_ent.date_ent < table_out.date_out
```

and then use aggregation to find the maximum date meeting that condition:

```
select o.cod_prod, o.date_out, e.cod_prod, max(e.date_ent) as date_ent
from table_out o
join table_ent e on e.cod_prod = o.cod_prod and e.date_ent < o.date_out
group by o.cod_prod, o.date_out, e.cod_prod
order by o.cod_prod, o.date_out;

  COD_PROD DATE_OUT     COD_PROD DATE_ENT  
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       362 2016-10-01        362 2015-09-16
       362 2016-10-07        362 2016-10-06
       362 2016-10-29        362 2016-10-25
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=452579a4021fbb2d18228c597a00b0d0)

---

I still don't understand the last row of your expected output but I think this must be close to what you want:

```
select a.cod_prod, a.date_out, a.vl_prod, b.cod_prod as cod_prod,
  max(b.vl_prod) keep (dense_rank last order by b.date_ent) as vl_prod, max(b.date_ent) as date_ent
from table_out a
join table_ent b on b.cod_prod = a.cod_prod and b.date_ent < a.date_out
group by a.cod_prod, a.date_out, b.cod_prod, a.vl_prod --, b.vl_prod
order by a.cod_prod;

  COD_PROD DATE_OUT      VL_PROD   COD_PROD    VL_PROD DATE_ENT  
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       362 2016-10-01        700        362         10 2015-09-16
       362 2016-10-01        800        362         10 2015-09-16
       362 2016-10-07        800        362        300 2016-10-06
       362 2016-10-29        100        362        810 2016-10-25
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6110a910ae05c8a519572513cfaba900)

Comment: I supose here is beter use <= in case dates is equal in both tables

Comment: With `<=` it would show 2016-10-07 as the `date_ent` on the second row instead of 2016-10-06, which wouldn't match the desired output in the question.

Comment: I need to get only the last date of closest entry.
can not have more than one result, the date of exit can not be less or equal to the date of entry

Comment: @alexTobias - that's what this answer does, isn't it?

Comment: this answer would only work if it did not have the vl_prod column

Comment: The question I answered did not have the `vl_prod` column. Like I said already, don't change the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Edit questions to add clarification, not to fundamentally change them. I'm going to roll your edit back again, and you should *ask a new* question, including the logic for the result you want, which isn't clear. I don't see why the two rows for 2016-10-01 have different results, or why the row for 2016-10-29 has 920 or 750. Make sure that is clear in your new question.

Comment: I edited because I can not create a new question. You have reached your question limit

Answer (score 0):

The closest day may be before or after.

This is sample where you got date which is closest from both side:

```
ith tab_1 as (
  select 362 id, to_date('14/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('15/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('16/09/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('05/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('06/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('07/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('08/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('23/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('24/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('25/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('30/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
),
 tab_2 as (
  select 362 id, to_date('01/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('07/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual union all
  select 362 id, to_date('29/10/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dat from dual
)
select 
  dat1_id,
  dat2_dat,
  dat2_dat
from (
  select 
    tab_2.id   dat1_id,
    tab_2.dat  dat1_dat,
    tab_1.dat  dat2_dat,
    row_number() over (partition by tab_2.id, tab_2.dat order by abs(tab_2.dat - tab_1.dat) asc) rn
  from
    tab_2
    inner join tab_1 
      on tab_2.id = tab_1.id
)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: The question says 'closest' but the title says 'last'; and the expected `date_ent` for the second row is the 06/10/2016 - whereas your version returns `07/10/2016` as that is closest, of course. So the OP seems to want the closest *previous* date. (The question isn't clear though...)

Comment: Yes, when you combine title and question i supose your answer is 'closest'... 

Comment: last date of entry and the closest date of departure